# Как убрать отображение количества ссылок в скрипте в VisualStudio

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот эти фразы: ссылок: 0, ссылок: 0, ссылок: 0... Очень мешают нормально структурировать функции, чтобы они шли подряд, а не через строку. К тому же информация о кол-ве ссылок функции мне абсолютно не нужна. Можно ли как-то скрыть эту информацию? Может, в настройках VisualStudio, или Юнити, для которого я пишу скрипт?

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, это называется code lens, оно отключается где то в настройках

Comment: [нашел](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019#:~:text=To%20disable%20CodeLens%2C%20choose%20Tools,CodeLens%2C%20and%20deselect%20the%20feature.)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо. Ваше решение помогло. Если вы напишите его в ответе, то я смогу его принять

Comment: Дело привычки, но оно несет очевидную пользу - можно всегда легко найти откуда есть ссылки на этот метод. Эта штука кликабельная, если что.

Comment: @aepot Да, но пока я только учусь и мои проекты не очень большие, я и так помню где какой метод. Я знаю, что она кликабельна:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется code lens, оно [отключается](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20CodeLens%2C%20choose%20Tools,CodeLens%2C%20and%20deselect%20the%20feature.) в настройках

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > CodeLens